UML: Can classes appear with dashed borders according to strict UML definition?
Questions - About whether UML classes can appear with dashed borders according to strict UML definition:
Note: Sometimes tool choice has an influence - the tool our company uses is EA.
(1) For UML classes, according to the strict UML 2.5.1 visual definition,
is there some circumstance where a class is displayed ("naturally") with a dashed border on a class diagram?

(2) If not, is there some way to make EA display on a class diagram a class with a dashed border ?

(3) re "Sharing" - in comparison with SysML:
if a SysML block is "shared" , as defined in a BBD diagram ...
(I mean "compositely shared", i.e., shared by aggregative composition/inclusion as opposed to sole exclusive composition/inclusion -- ),...
... then when the block appears in an IBD diagram (as a 'property', I assume), it appears with a dashed border line. This indicates that it is shared -- and not exclusively owned by any other block.
Q: So I have done a test with EA to create a compositely shared class to see if it shows a dashed border. It does not. Maybe there is some UML defined way to do this?
Thanks

I don't get it. You seem to be trying to make UML look like SysML in EA. Why not use SysML in the first place?

Somebody at work used UML/EA to enter an IFD (information flow diagram) as a "class-tree" to show how a tree of multi-layered & multi-channel flows, from one class to another, they meet and produce the final output objects.
Now, 90% of the classes are all contained in the same repository (a git SM), and about 10% are from other repositories (external). They want to indicate the "external" classes by highlighting them with a dashed border. They could not do that in UML.
So far, I have found it can be done in SysML, and also by Shape scripts, I guess, which you can also run in UML.

The SysML-ibd is called composite structure diagram in UML. It has the same notation for shared aggregation, namely the dashed rectangle you mention.


The SysML-ibd is called composite structure diagram in UML. It has the same notation for shared aggregation, namely the dashed rectangle you mention.

Ok - When I tried, it did not work. I will have another go.
Now, is that shared aggregation of classes?
or components?
Both?

Class or Components are treated the same. Please note, that not the Class is shown with a dashed border. It is the role (other names: Attribute, property, reference). For example when you have a class Order that references a Person as gift receiver it would be shown in the composite structure diagram of the Order in a dashed rectangle labeled gift receiver:Person.
